# Counting electrons in Ozonolysis

Tags: electrons, oxidation-state, organic-oxidation, ozone

I can't understand the electron count made on this page about Ozonolysis. ([http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/ozonolysis/Oz.html](http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/%7Echem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS/ozonolysis/Oz.html))

This is the specific part of the article:
[image: Ozonide oxidation level]
From my calculations the oxidation of an alkene to an ozonide is a 4 electrons oxidation and not 6e, in fact the two carbons in the double bond loses 2e each from bonding two oxygens.
Anyway I agree with the 4e oxidation from alkene to two carbonyl compounds. Where am I wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You misstated what you read. Formation of the ozonide from an alkene is a 6-electron oxidation. The dimethyl sulfide is oxidized to dimethyl sulfoxide by 2-electrons meaning that the ozonide is reduced by 2-electrons. So alkene to two carbonyl compounds is a net 4-electron oxidation. Welcome to ChemSE. Good choice of citation!

Comment: Thank you for your comment. In other words I can't understand why ozonide formation from alkene is a 6-electron oxidation (instead of 4-electron that I calculated).

Comment: I don't know how you count. If you accept that alkene --> 2 carbonyls is a 4e oxidation and DMS --> DMSO is a 2e oxidation then alkene --> ozonide must be a 6e oxidation. Read the link on oxidation levels in your citation.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But if the problem was to calculate the electrons number involved in the oxidation of an alkene to form an ozonide (as in the link on oxidation levels in the citation), how would you do?

P.S.: So not deducing that the number is 6 from indirect path

Comment: The oxidation levels link only assigned charges to a Grignard reagent but used partial charges in all other examples to determine the polarity of the bonds. Assigning charges to every atom in an organic compound (sounds like homework) is not a productive exercise. You want the relative change. The method used is direct. Let me say that I am quite familiar with the intent of the author of the website you have cited. If you want, I will expand on the explanation with an Answer. https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to demonstrate that the addition of ozone to an alkene is a 6-electron oxidation of the carbon framework, here are two methods. To assign a charge to the carbon atoms of a neutral compound (sum of all charges equals zero) treat all hydrogens as +1 and all oxygens as -2, then do the math. Each carbon in ethylene (**1**) has a calculated (in red) value of -2. Molozonide **2** has carbons with a charge of +1 but, for convenience, they are written as zero and +2. Already one can see that **1** $\rightarrow$ **2** is a 6-electron oxidation [-4e $\rightarrow$ +2e]. Collapse of the molozonide gives formaldehyde (**3**) of carbon charge zero and zwitterion **4** with carbon charge +2. These species recombine to form ozonide **7** that has the same carbon charge as the molozonide **2**. That the zwitterion **4** is the equivalent of formic acid **6**, follow the steps **4** $\rightarrow$ **5** $\rightarrow$ **6**. Thus, both the molozonide **2** and ozonide **7** are equivalent to one formaldehyde and one formic acid.
Alternatively, oxidation of ethylene (**1**) to ethylene glycol (**8**) [-4e $\rightarrow$ -2e] is a 2-electron oxidation and a second 2-electron  oxidation [-2e $\rightarrow$ 0e] affords two moles of formaldehyde. Oxidation of one of the formaldehydes to formic acid [0e $\rightarrow$ +2e) is the third 2-electron oxidation. Both pathways demonstrate that the oxidation of ethylene to formaldehyde and formic acid are 6-electron oxidations.

[image]